# Using node.io with a web server

Tags: node.js, node.io

I have started this web scraping project backwards by beginning with node.io.  I have it working such that:

```
node.io myjob arg1 arg2
```

Will emit the results in JSON format:

```
{
    1 : 'apple',
    2 : 'orange',
    3 : 'banana'
}
```

My goal is to be able to run this in a web server so if I point to:

```
http://localhost/arg1/arg2
```

It will be able to execute the `node.io myjob arg1 arg2` command with the arguments and retrieve my JSON output.

I have looked through node.js but I cannot find any examples of it using node.io or vice versa to create the web server.  I know I am working backwards but this is where I am stuck currently.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the standard [built-in web server with Node.js](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener), and when a request comes in with the correct parameters, programmatically start your scraping job.

Comment: Thanks @Brad but how do I execute a node.io job from within my script?

Comment: nm...I figured it out.  I need to use nodeio.start() to start a job from within a script =)

Comment: @AllenLiu Am also looking for something similar. Can you share any resources or your work for reference